# image processing commands in python using for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have this part code which i don't understand the for loop part: 
also what does file path holds and how it is different than all file path?

```
all_files_path = glob.glob("ADNI1_Screening_1.5T/ADNI/*/*/*/*/*.nii")


for file_path in all_file_path:
    print(os.system("./runROBEX.sh " + file_path + " stripped/" +file_path.split("/")[-1]))
```

Comment: `all_files_path[0].split("/")[2]` does nothing useful: the result is discarded.

Comment: the script seems to apply the same shell command on all files resolved by the above pattern.